# JPA Three different tables foreign key in one table mapping

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table which have three different tables foreign key. I want to map it but it is not inserting data together. here is the table detail

```
id
analysis_type_id
product_id
edition_id
```

`product_id` is a foreign key to `product` table. `edition_id` is a foreign key to `edition` table. `analysis_type_id` is a foreign key to `analysis_type` table.

here is the classes mapping

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "t_analysis_type", catalog = "")
    public class TAnalysisTypeEntity implements Serializable {
    private Collection<TProductEntity> tProductEntities;
    private Collection<TProductEditionEntity> tProductEditionEntities;

    @ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "product_edition_analysis_type_map",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "analysis_type_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    )
    public Collection<TProductEntity> gettProductEntities() {
        return tProductEntities;
    }

    public void settProductEntities(Collection<TProductEntity> tProductEntities) {
        this.tProductEntities = tProductEntities;
    }

    @ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "product_edition_analysis_type_map",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "analysis_type_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "edition_id")
    )
    public Collection<TProductEditionEntity> gettProductEditionEntities() {
        return tProductEditionEntities;
    }
    public void settProductEditionEntities(Collection<TProductEditionEntity> tProductEditionEntities) {
        this.tProductEditionEntities = tProductEditionEntities;
    }
}
```

Product Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_product", catalog = "")
public class TProductEntity implements Serializable {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tProductEntities")
    public Collection<TAnalysisTypeEntity> gettAnalysisTypeEntities() {
        return tAnalysisTypeEntities;
    }

    public void settAnalysisTypeEntities(Collection<TAnalysisTypeEntity> tAnalysisTypeEntities) {
        this.tAnalysisTypeEntities = tAnalysisTypeEntities;
    }

}
```

Product Edition Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_product_edition", catalog = "")
public class TProductEditionEntity implements Serializable {
    private Collection<TAnalysisTypeEntity> tAnalysisTypeEntities;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tProductEditionEntities")
    public Collection<TAnalysisTypeEntity> gettAnalysisTypeEntities() {
        return tAnalysisTypeEntities;
    }

    public void settAnalysisTypeEntities(Collection<TAnalysisTypeEntity> tAnalysisTypeEntities) {
        this.tAnalysisTypeEntities = tAnalysisTypeEntities;
    }
}
```

Now The problem is when I try to insert a product with edition to analysis type it adds two row to the table. Code is below. it adds two rows

```
TAnalysisTypeEntity tAnalysisTypeEntity = tAnalysisTypeRepository.findOne(10001);
        TProductEntity tProductEntity = tProductRepository.findOne(1);

        List<TProductEntity> tProductEntities = new ArrayList<>();
        tProductEntities.add(tProductEntity);

        TProductEditionEntity tProductEditionEntity = tProductEditionRepository.findOne(1);
        List<TProductEditionEntity> tProductEditionEntities = new ArrayList<>();
        tProductEditionEntities.add(tProductEditionEntity);

        tAnalysisTypeEntity.settProductEditionEntities(tProductEditionEntities);
        tAnalysisTypeEntity.settProductEntities(tProductEntities);
        tAnalysisTypeRepository.save(tAnalysisTypeEntity);
```

Rows:

```
'5','10001',NULL,'1'
'6','10001','1',NULL
```

I want data like this

```
'5','10001','1','1'
```

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox can you please answer?

Comment: No. You cannot "share" a join table for multiple relationships.